# How is the key shared between tag and reader in RFID mutual AES protocol?

Tags: aes, rfid

In the RFID mutual authentication protocol, how and where are data stored? What data is stored in the tag, reader and server (database) before first time of communication?

For example, in the AES-128 protocol, the tag, reader and server share a key at first time for authentication and communicate with each other. But hos is that key shared so the reader knows that the tag is not fake?